# How to render ₹ symbol in PDF in C# using PDFsharp

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, pdfsharp

I want to render ₹ in PDF using C#.
Instead of this I am getting ?.

In form am able to print how to render ₹ but I am facing this issue only with PDF.

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zNAt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Unicode is enabled in PDFsharp and also make sure the font use are using contains that symbol.

Since you get "?" instead of the symbol, you most likely just have to set the `PdfFontEncoding.Unicode` option as shown in the sample.

See this sample:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx